# How do I update/edit my old Alexa Skills?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to edit my old Alexa Skill for the recent Alexa Developer Perks Contest and I don't know how to? Is there any certain set of instructions to edit the code in the AWS Lambda Portal?

I've looked through the options and can't find an edit button.

I don't have any code.

No error messages.

Comment: Please Help ME!!!

Comment: Did you use ask-cli to deploy the code?

Comment: What do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into cloning your skill like this:

```
ask clone [Skill ID]
```

See here for your reference:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#clone-command